# Does the cost of Career Change increase by character or by player?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society, organized-play

It costs 50 ACP in PFS to rebuild your character. The cost can increase:

> Each additional purchase adds 15 points to the total cost.

**Is this per player, or per character?**
If I rebuild a character twice, that is clearly 115 ACP. But rebuilding 2 characters once each, is it 100 or 115 ACP?

(trying out would be a bit costly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the [Pathfinder Society FAQ](https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/faq), there's a bullet with the full text of Career Change:

> [ ] Career Change (Limited-Use, Service): Your existing abilities have helped you achieve success in the field, but you’re overdue for a drastic change if you’re to continue succeeding in the adventures to come. Between adventures, you can check the box that precedes this boon to completely rebuild your character. Remove everything your character has purchased with gp, as well as their class, feats, skill proficiencies, and related features. You may not alter the character's ancestry, heritage or background, but you may change the ability score boosts you selected at character creation. Your character’s wealth is set to 85% of the total gold you’ve earned—this reduction represents a small amount lost from consumable use as well as items sold back for a particularly favorable rate. This rebuilding process does not change the amount of Fame, Reputation, or gp the character has earned, nor does it change the resources your character has expended on services such as spellcasting.
>
> You can also refund any faction boons for the Fame price at which you purchased them, though you cannot sell back Limited-Use boons that you have expended or Faction Champion boons that you have used to earn Reputation for a faction.
>
> All changes to the character must be applied by the time the character next plays an adventure; once the adventure begins, no further changes can be made with this boon.

Based on the Limited-Use tag and the singular checkbox for Career Change it seems that this can only be selected once per character, so the increased cost would only make sense to apply on a per player basis.